# Difference between 'to belch' and 'to burp'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Although most dictionaries I have looked these verbs up in define them in very much the same way,

> to belch: emit wind noisily from the stomach through the mouth
>
> to burp: noisily release air from the stomach through the mouth; belch

(Oxford Online Dictionary)

I feel (from the times I have come across these verbs in reading) that there is a  difference between these two verbs. Can a native speaker of English confirm or infirm, and, of course, should they confirm, refine these definitions, although there is nothing refined about it all!

Comment: I would say that a belch is more vulgar. A burp can be suppressed, and barely audible. A belch can be a deliberate expression of satisfaction with onesself, or disapproval of others.

Comment: Yeah, I would tend to agree with Weather Vane. I always connect "belch" with drinking too much beer too fast.

Comment: Basically it depends on which term most closely resembles the sound produced.

Comment: *Belch* means louder, longer, more noticeable.  It's a particular type of burp.

Answer (score 3):

***Belch***

is an older word.

> Old English bealcan "bring up wind from the stomach," also "swell, heave," of echoic origin (compare Dutch balken "to bray, shout"). Extended to volcanoes, cannons, etc. 1570s. Related: Belched; belching. As a noun, "an act of belching," it is recorded from 1510s; also slang for "poor beer, malt liquor" (1706).

[-Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=belch)

[***Burp***](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=burp) is more recent

> 1932, noun and verb, American English, apparently imitative. The transitive sense of the verb is attested by 1940. Related: Burped; burping. Burp-gun attested from 1945.

An older word from the Latin is probably...

[***eructation*** (n.)](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=eructation)

"belching," 1530s, from Latin eructationem (nominative eructatio) "a belching forth," noun of action from past participle stem of eructare "to belch forth, vomit," from assimilated form of ex "out" (see ex-) + ructare "to belch," from PIE *reug- "to belch"

As I said in a comment, "belch" is probably related to beer, and its consumption. Most native speakers would relate "belch" to a louder and more vulgar description.

Comment: And, notably, a "burp" is what a small child produces (though sometimes accompanied by a variable volume of "spit up").

Comment: @HotLicks Absolutely right. After all, we do not say "to belch" the baby. Before there was "to burp the baby" what was there?

Comment: [Nothing.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=burp+the+baby&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cburp%20the%20baby%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Though, interestingly, "burping" is mainly associated with [bottle feeding](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=burp+the+baby%2Cbaby+bottle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cburp%20the%20baby%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbaby%20bottle%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @HotLicks this sounds like a good Q...

Comment: That is what I thought: I imagined 'belching' to be more 'loaded' than 'burping', 'wind' and 'gas' being euphemisms for nastier material than just 'air'. Could be a prelude to barfing!

Comment: @HotLicks - Well, no.  I think you must be thinking of how different the poop smells.

Comment: @aparente001 - Babies have more of a tendency to swallow air when bottle feeding than when breast feeding.

Comment: @HotLicks - There's this thing called an *overactive letdown reflex*, in which the milk is delivered like water out of a fireman's hose.  If the baby isn't burped carefully in a timely way, you can end up changing all the clothes and bedding in the middle of the night and starting from scratch with feeding.  There is apparently a way to adjust for the overactive letdown reflex (nurse for a moment to get the flow started, then let the initial strong flow go into a folded cloth and make the baby wait a minute or two until the flow calms down), but we didn't know about this until much later.

Comment: @aparente001 - "Poop" isn't directly associated with either belching or burping.

Comment: @HotLicks - This is interesting.  (Although totally off topic!)  I googled your claim and found this: https://www.babycenter.com/404_is-it-true-that-breastfed-babies-dont-need-to-be-burped_10329122.bc. // The only connection to the poop topic was *difference between nursed baby vs. bottle baby.*